# .css and .html are not located in the same directory

Tags: html, css, django

`mystyle.css` file :

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr, th, td {
    border: solid 1px #fff
}
td {
    width: 50px;
    padding: 15px
}
th {
    background: #006599;
    color: #fff
}
table.inner tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #c7d4e5
}
table.inner tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #E5E5E5
}
h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0.3em 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
}
h2 {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-top: 0.4em;
}
address {
    padding: 0.8em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
page {
    background: white;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
}
page[size="A4"] {
    width: 21cm;
    height: 29.7cm;
}
page[size="A4"][layout="portrait"] {
    width: 29.7cm;
    height: 21cm;
}
page[size="A3"] {
    width: 29.7cm;
    height: 42cm;
}
page[size="A3"][layout="portrait"] {
    width: 42cm;
    height: 29.7cm;
}
page[size="A5"] {
    width: 14.8cm;
    height: 21cm;
}
page[size="A5"][layout="portrait"] {
    width: 21cm;
    height: 14.8cm;
}
.header, .content {
    padding-right: 30%;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.border {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}
.border td, .border th {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 4px 8px;
}
@media print {
    body, page {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .djDebug {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media screen {
    html {
        background: #999;
    }
    body {
        margin: 20px 30%;
        padding-top: 3em;
        padding-left: 3em;
    }
}
```

My `.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <!--put all your javascript library or style here-->
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

    <script>
    window.print()
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    {% load i18n %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <center>
                    <h1>Test - {% trans "Customer profile" %}</h1>
                    <center></center>
                </center>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{% trans "Date" %}</td>
            <td>{% now "jS F Y" %}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{% trans "Customer id" %}</td>
            <td>{{ customerprofile.amortizing_table_context.customer_code}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class='inner'>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">
                            <h2>{% trans "General informations" %}</h2>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "First name" %}</td>
                        <td class="col-md-9">{{ customerprofile.amortizing_table_context.first_name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Last name" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.amortizing_table_context.last_name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Email" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.email}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Language" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.language }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Primary phone" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.phone_1 }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Secondary phone" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.phone_2 }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Fax" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.fax }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Social Security number (SSN)" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.ssn }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Birth date" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.birth_date }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Principal address" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.address }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Secondary address" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.address_line2}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "City" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.city }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "State" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.state }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Zip code" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.zip_code }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class='inner'>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">
                            <h2>{% trans "Financial" %}</h2>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Income source" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.income_source }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Bank" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.bank }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Bank transit" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.bank_transit }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Bank account" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.bank_account }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Monthly pay amount" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.pay_amount }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Pay frequency" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.pay_frequency }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "First pay date" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.first_pay_date }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Second pay date" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.second_pay_date }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Monthly micro loan amount" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.micro_loan_monthly_amount }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Account balance on pay day" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.financialprofile.bank_account_balance_on_pay_day }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Bankruptcy" %}</td>
                        <td>{% if customerprofile.financialprofile.had_bankruptcy %} {{ "Yes" }}{% else %}{{ "No" }} {% endif %}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Consumer proposal" %}</td>
                        <td>{% if customerprofile.financialprofile.had_consumer_proposal %} {{ "Yes" }}{% else %}{{ "No" }} {% endif %}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class='inner'>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">
                            <h2>{% trans "Employer" %}</h2>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Company name" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.company_name }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Job title" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.job_title }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Date hired" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.date_hired }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Supervisor name" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.supervisor_name }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Phone" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.phone }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Phone extension" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.phone_extension }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Address" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.address }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Secondary address" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.address_line2 }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "City" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.city }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "State" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.state }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Zip code" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.employerprofile.zip_code }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class='inner'>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">
                            <h2>{% trans "References" %}</h2>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Reference 1 - Fullname" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.referencesprofile.ref1_fullname }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Reference 1 - Phone" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.referencesprofile.ref1_phone }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Reference 1 - Link" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.referencesprofile.ref1_link }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Reference 2 - Fullname" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.referencesprofile.ref2_fullname }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Reference 2 - Phone" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.referencesprofile.ref2_phone }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% trans "Reference 2 - Link" %}</td>
                        <td>{{ customerprofile.referencesprofile.ref2_link }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

The `.html` file and `.css` file are not located in the same directory. The first one is located in `/home/jeremie/Projects/Test-Django/loanwolf/templates/loanwol‌​f/customers` and `mystyle.css` is located in `/home/jeremie/Projects/Test-Django/loanwolf/static/loanwolf/‌​css`. How could I modify the line `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">` in such a way it works?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/home/jeremie/Projects/Test-Django/loanwolf/static/loanwolf/‌​css/mystyle.css">

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../loanwolf/static/loanwolf/css/mystyle.css" type="text/css">

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clean a html document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43012924/clean-a-html-document)

Comment: The directory of the HTML file is *completely irrelevant*, as Django does not serve it directly but renders it as a template.

Comment: @jdoe Did any of the following answers helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% load static %}    

<!DOCTYPE html>

...

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/mystyle.css' %}">
```

All the above assumes that you have set correctly the [`STATIC` settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#static-files). See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/) for more on static files.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the href to: href="../css/mystyle.css"

Answer (score -1):

If it is not in the same folder, you must specify the path to the file. There is the absolute path (like the one in the comments to your question) and there is the relative path. The absolute path means you specify the full path starting from the root. The relative path it's... Well... Relative to the path of yout html file.

Use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../static/loanwolf/css/mystyle.css">` to get it by its relative path. The `..` means the parent folder.